# How to store the script output in the variable inside the jenkins sh """ block

Tags: shell, jenkins, groovy

I want to store the script output in the variable from the jenkins sh """ block.

I have tried like this but it doesn't work. Can anyone help me to resolve this error?

```
stage("Test stage") {
   steps {
       sh """
          source setup_env.sh (setting up the environment variables needed for test script to run)
          cd ${Test_scrip_path}
          def script_status = ./unit_test.sh
       """
   }
}
```

Comment: `def` is not a shell command, and of course, the shell you are running as a child process of Jenkins cannot set variables in the parent Jenkins process.

Comment: Also, please don't spam tags; this has nothing with [tag:python] to do.